# Php page execution time while working with Stored procedures, PDO

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, execute

I am Working with PHP, MS Sql. For this i am using PDOs. Here i am fetching data by using Stored procedures. problem is It is working fine for less execution time i.e 6 secs (Manual db test). If execution time increases, It sends empty result set to PHP page. This is the code i am using. Please tell me the solution for this one.

```
$tsql = "EXECUTE dbo.rrproc_get_res ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";
$count = $sqlserver_db->prepare($tsql);
$count->bindParam(1, $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$count->bindParam(2, $getKeywords, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count->bindParam(3, $s1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count->bindParam(4, $s2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count->bindParam(5, $m, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$count->execute();

// Get the number of rows returned. 
 $totalRows = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Stored Procedure
.....................

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rrproc_get__search_state] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @time as int ,  
    @searchkeyword as varchar(500),
    @state as varchar(200)

    AS
    BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
      Set nocount on

   DECLARE @fullsearchkeyword varchar(500)  
   Set @fullsearchkeyword = '"'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@searchkeyword,'"',''), ',', '" OR "') + '"'  


/* To Find all Cities in that State*/

     Declare @City1 Varchar(200)


    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_CITY(Id int Identity(1,1) not null,CITY_NAME VARCHAR(200))

   -- Select distinct city From zip_codes where state='NY'

Declare @temp varchar(8000)

Declare db_cursor Cursor For
       select distinct city From zip_codes where state=@state
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @City1
While @@FEtch_status =0
Begin

INSERT INTO #TEMP_CITY VALUES(@City1)
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @City1
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

 /* End of Find Nearest Cities*/


 Set @searchkeyword = '"'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@searchkeyword,'"',''), ',', '" AND "') + '"' 

  /*Removing Duplicate City Names*/
  DELETE FROM #TEMP_CITY WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID)FROM #TEMP_CITY GROUP BY CITY_NAME)



DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ' ', '') +  CITY_NAME FROM #TEMP_CITY
SELECT @temp=@Names
--print @temp   

--select count(*) from #TEMP_CITY

Declare @fullsearch varchar(1000)
set @fullsearch=@temp
--Print @fullsearch

 declare @Result varchar(8000)
set  @Result = ''
select  @Result = @Result + case when len(@Result)>0 then ' OR ' else '' end + CITY_NAME
from #TEMP_CITY

DECLARE @searchkeyword2 varchar(5000) 
DECLARE @fullsearchkeyword2 varchar(5000) 
--set  @searchkeyword='C++ OR JANK KIT OR MAT'
set  @searchkeyword2=@Result

Set @fullsearchkeyword2 = '"'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@searchkeyword2,'"',''), ' OR ', '" OR "') + '"'  



  SELECT  count(r_id)  FROM rr_table  where (CONTAINS(r_text,@fullsearchkeyword2))  
        and (CONTAINS(r_text,@searchkeyword)) 
        and r_creation_time > DATEADD(dd, -@time, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1)))  
        and (r_text IS NOT NULL AND datalength(r_text)!=0) 



  DROP TABLE #TEMP_CITY

 END
```

Comment: Any suggestions plz.... any other methods?

Comment: How long does the stored procedure take to execute if executed using something like phpMyAdmin? Sharing the contents of the SP would help.

Comment: @gvee, as per my observation, its not working when execution time exceeds 8 secs.

Comment: why don't you share your query and maybe we can make it a bit more efficient? You have an issue with a timeout and I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with PDO to know where to set the connection timeout.

Comment: @gvee, I can't able to share stored procedure in Comments section. Just I edit the Main Post with SP. Please check

Comment: that's a lot of cursors! I am certain that it can be made more efficient by making a lot (if not all of it set-based). Unfortunately I simply don't have the time right now to spend the time doing that at this moment.

Comment: @gvee, thanks for ur suggestions and ur valuble time. basically i am PHP developer. I tried my level best to write effective SP. Please help when u ll be free.

Comment: @gvee, here no need to create Temp Table. Temp Table Created only for removing duplicate Cities. can you please rewrite that part direct query with distinct Cities, If you have time.. It may solve my problem.